# Unique en laravel 8 (insert y update)

Tags: php, laravel, validación, formrequest

Valido el formulario de registro de usuario atraves de FormRequest y funciona como yo quiero a la perfeccion pero al usar el mismo FormRequest para el update me dice que el dni del usuario ya existe, entonces trato de crear una excepcion junto a unique de esta forma:

```
'dni' => 'bail|required|unique:users,' . $this->id,
```

Tambien intente de esta forma :

```
Rule::unique('users', 'dni')->ignore($this->user->id),
```

Pero no se como  se obtiene o de donde sale el id del usuario a excluir, ojo que las validaciones las hago en un FormRequest y no en un controlador.

Answer (score 1):

Para añadir una excepción debe estar en el tercer parámetro de unique, el segundo es el nombre de la columna

```
'dni' => 'bail|required|unique:users,dni,' . $this->id
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener primero el usuario actual en el formRequest asi:

```
$user = $this->route()->parameter('user');
```

y luego si colocar la regla:

```
Rule::unique('users', 'dni')->ignore($user->dni),
```